# How can i set PayPal discount code in my PayPal account?

Tags: wordpress, paypal

I need to set discount code in my Paypal account so one can use it at the time of checkout.

Paypal suggests to generate a 'Buy now' button source-code but I don't want to follow this way because I'm registering user with Paid Membership Pro plugin in WordPress and needs the create discount codes for users.

Is there any way to set the discount code direct in Paypal?
Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Paid Membership Pro has a discount feature in the system.

Please refer here: http://www.paidmembershipspro.com/documentation/discount-codes/

Comment: Thanks mate for the best response.
These discount codes are working fine for me.

But Actually,
I want the appearance of this discount code at my Paypal transaction history.

That would be great if you can suggest me any way for this, If it is.